# NodeList event not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a event calendar. The problem i'm having is that every time insert a event to a specific date, my other events innerHTML changes as well.

I have tried event.stopPropagation(),as well as, event.stopImmediatePropagation().

This doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions in how i can make this work?

Thank you in advance!

```js
let dates = document.querySelectorAll(".calendar-date button.date-item");
dates.forEach(function(date){
  date.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    let parentNode = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
    let events = parentNode.querySelector(".calendar-events");
    document.querySelector("#add-modal").classList.add("active");
    let form = document.querySelector("#add-event").addEventListener("submit",function(formEvent){
      formEvent.preventDefault();
      document.querySelector("#add-modal").classList.remove("active");
      let inputValue = this.querySelector("input[name='event-input']");
      events.innerHTML = '<a class="calendar-event bg-success text-light" href="#calendars">'+inputValue.value+'</a>';
    });
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/spectre.css/dist/spectre-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/spectre.css/dist/spectre-exp.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/spectre.css/dist/spectre.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Spectre Calendar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="calendar calendar-lg">
      <!-- calendar navbar structure -->
      <div class="calendar-nav navbar">
        <button class="btn btn-action btn-link btn-lg">
          <i class="icon icon-arrow-left"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-primary">August 2018</div>
        <button class="btn btn-action btn-link btn-lg">
          <i class="icon icon-arrow-right"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="calendar-container">
      <!-- calendar header structure -->
        <div class="calendar-header">
          <div class="calendar-date">SUN</div>
          <div class="calendar-date">MON</div>
          <div class="calendar-date">TUE</div>
          <div class="calendar-date">WED</div>
          <div class="calendar-date">THU</div>
          <div class="calendar-date">FRI</div>
          <div class="calendar-date">SAT</div>
        </div>

        <div class="calendar-body">
          <!-- calendar date with events -->

          <!-- calendar prev month days -->
          <div class="calendar-date prev-month">
            <button class="date-item">29</button>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date prev-month">
            <button class="date-item">30</button>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date prev-month">
            <button class="date-item">31</button>
          </div>

          <!-- calendar current month days -->
          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">1</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">2</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">3</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">4</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">5</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">6</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">7</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">8</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item date-today">9</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">10</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">11</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">12</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">13</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">14</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">15</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item disabled">16</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">17</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">18</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">19</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">20</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">21</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">22</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">23</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">24</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">25</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">26</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">27</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">28</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">29</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">30</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">31</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <!-- calendar next month -->
          <div class="calendar-date next-month">
            <button class="date-item">1</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--ADD EVENT MODAL-->
    <div class="modal" id="add-modal">
      <a href="#close" class="modal-overlay" aria-label="Close"></a>
      <div class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <a href="#close" class="btn btn-clear float-right" aria-label="Close"></a>
          <div class="modal-title h5">Add Event</div>
        </div>
        <form id="add-event">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="content">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-input" type="text" name="event-input" placeholder="Type text here...">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you click a date, you add a listener to the "Submit" action that changes its inner html, so your dates end up listening to this "submit" action forever.

One quick way to fix this is to remove the listener after you are done editing the innerHtml or set it up to only trigger once with `{once: true}`.

```js
let dates = document.querySelectorAll(".calendar-date button.date-item");
dates.forEach(function(date){
  date.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    let parentNode = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
    let events = parentNode.querySelector(".calendar-events");
    document.querySelector("#add-modal").classList.add("active");
    let form = document.querySelector("#add-event").addEventListener("submit",function(formEvent){
      formEvent.preventDefault();
      document.querySelector("#add-modal").classList.remove("active");
      let inputValue = this.querySelector("input[name='event-input']");
      events.innerHTML = '<a class="calendar-event bg-success text-light" href="#calendars">'+inputValue.value+'</a>';
    }, {once: true});
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/spectre.css/dist/spectre-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/spectre.css/dist/spectre-exp.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/spectre.css/dist/spectre.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Spectre Calendar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="calendar calendar-lg">
      <!-- calendar navbar structure -->
      <div class="calendar-nav navbar">
        <button class="btn btn-action btn-link btn-lg">
          <i class="icon icon-arrow-left"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-primary">August 2018</div>
        <button class="btn btn-action btn-link btn-lg">
          <i class="icon icon-arrow-right"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="calendar-container">
      <!-- calendar header structure -->
        <div class="calendar-header">
          <div class="calendar-date">SUN</div>
          <div class="calendar-date">MON</div>
          <div class="calendar-date">TUE</div>
          <div class="calendar-date">WED</div>
          <div class="calendar-date">THU</div>
          <div class="calendar-date">FRI</div>
          <div class="calendar-date">SAT</div>
        </div>

        <div class="calendar-body">
          <!-- calendar date with events -->

          <!-- calendar prev month days -->
          <div class="calendar-date prev-month">
            <button class="date-item">29</button>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date prev-month">
            <button class="date-item">30</button>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date prev-month">
            <button class="date-item">31</button>
          </div>

          <!-- calendar current month days -->
          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">1</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">2</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">3</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">4</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">5</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">6</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">7</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">8</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item date-today">9</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">10</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">11</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">12</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">13</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">14</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">15</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item disabled">16</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">17</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">18</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">19</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">20</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">21</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">22</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">23</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">24</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">25</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">26</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">27</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">28</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">29</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">30</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="calendar-date">
            <button class="date-item">31</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

          <!-- calendar next month -->
          <div class="calendar-date next-month">
            <button class="date-item">1</button>
            <div class="calendar-events"></div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--ADD EVENT MODAL-->
    <div class="modal" id="add-modal">
      <a href="#close" class="modal-overlay" aria-label="Close"></a>
      <div class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <a href="#close" class="btn btn-clear float-right" aria-label="Close"></a>
          <div class="modal-title h5">Add Event</div>
        </div>
        <form id="add-event">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="content">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-input" type="text" name="event-input" placeholder="Type text here...">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```